# WPF icon repository

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I have list of icon which will be displayed for different button i.e. save delete.
what I want to do is to list down all the icons in some xaml file like app.xaml

```
<Resource x:Key="error"  Source="Icons/Error.ico" />              
<Resource x:Key="save"  Source="Icons/save.ico" />
```

then want to access same thing in individual file as follow.

```
Icon="{Binding save}"
```

I would appreciate if someone suggest me correct approach if this is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create resource dictionary `Images.xaml`
2. Add all images to that dictionary in this form

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon1"
                    UriSource="Images/icon1.png" />
      .....
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
3. When you want to use it,

   ```
   <Image Source={StaticResource Icon1} />
   ```

Dont forgot to include that Image.xaml, to the place where you want to use it... actually you can merge it directly to your main dictionary in App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Images.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```